# SIGSEV in custom QuickSort implementation

Tags: delphi, pascal, quicksort

I slept over the answer to question [Quicksort drama](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24335585/quicksort-drama) and wanted to recode it from scratch, implementing your tip with the call-by-reference var. And again: I cannot find any failure I made again. I compare the code to your program one by one and I cannot find the problem. The following code  produces an Exception (External:SIGSEV at address 11602) during compilation/run

```
program quicksort;

var
  iArray : array[0..8] of integer;

procedure fillArray(var iArray : array of integer);
begin;
  iArray[0] := 3;
  iArray[1] := 1;
  iArray[2] := 8;
  iArray[3] := 4;
  iArray[4] := 9;
  iArray[5] := 0;
  iArray[6] := 8;
  iArray[7] := 2;
  iArray[8] := 5;
end;

procedure writeArray(iArray : array of integer);
var i:integer;
begin
  for i:=low(iArray) to high(iArray) do begin
    write(iArray[i]);
  end;
  writeln('');
end;

procedure quickSort(var iArray : array of integer; links : integer; rechts:integer);
var
  l,r,pivot, temp: integer;
begin
  if (rechts > links) then begin
    l := links;
    r := rechts;
    pivot := iArray[(rechts+links) div 2];

    while (l<r) do begin
      while (iArray[l] < pivot) do l:=l+1;
      while (iArray[r] > pivot) do r:=r-1;
      if (l<=r) then begin
       temp := iArray[l];
       iArray[l] := iArray[r];
       iArray[r] := temp;
      end;
    end;
    if (links < r) then quickSort(iArray, links, r);
    if (l < rechts) then quickSort(iArray, l, rechts);
  end;
end;

begin
  fillArray(iArray);
  quickSort(iArray,low(iArray),high(iArray));
  writeArray(iArray);
end.
```

Comment: This is borderline off-topic for Stack Overflow, which is not a site for debugging sessions on your code (once there was a close reason "too localized", which would have been apt). To increase the chances of it being useful for future visitors of the site, you should edit it to have a meaningful title (something that can be searched for by people experiencing the same problem you had), properly formatted code and no German parameter names.

Comment: Could you, please, start to develop the habit to get your indentation right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The block of code that swaps, also needs to increment `l` and decrement `r` once the swap is complete:

```
if (l <= r) then
begin
  temp := iArray[l];
  iArray[l] := iArray[r];
  iArray[r] := temp;
  inc(l); // <-- this was missing
  dec(r); // <-- as was this
end;
```

The complete program, with some other minor tidy ups:

```
program quicksort24340509;

var
  iArray: array [0 .. 8] of integer;

Procedure fillArray(var iArray: array of integer);
begin;

  iArray[0] := 3;
  iArray[1] := 1;
  iArray[2] := 8;
  iArray[3] := 4;
  iArray[4] := 9;
  iArray[5] := 0;
  iArray[6] := 8;
  iArray[7] := 2;
  iArray[8] := 5;
end;

Procedure writeArray(const iArray: array of integer);
var
  i: integer;
begin
  for i := low(iArray) to high(iArray) do
  begin
    write(iArray[i], ' ');
  end;
  writeln;
end;

Procedure quickSort(var iArray: array of integer; links, rechts: integer);
var
  l, r, pivot, temp: integer;
begin
  if (rechts > links) then
  begin
    l := links;
    r := rechts;
    pivot := iArray[(rechts + links) div 2];

    while l < r do
    begin
      while iArray[l] < pivot do inc(l);
      while iArray[r] > pivot do dec(r);
      if l <= r then
      begin
        temp := iArray[l];
        iArray[l] := iArray[r];
        iArray[r] := temp;
        inc(l);
        dec(r);
      end;
    end;
    if links < r then
      quickSort(iArray, links, r);
    if l < rechts then
      quickSort(iArray, l, rechts);
  end;
end;

begin
  fillArray(iArray);
  quickSort(iArray, low(iArray), high(iArray));
  writeArray(iArray);
  readln;
end.
```

**Output**

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 8 8 9
```

---

The reason that your version fails, without the missing lines, is that the recursive calls to `quickSort` operate on the wrong ranges.

For example, Given your input of

```
3 1 8 4 9 0 8 2 5
```

the partitioning step pivots on `9` and results in

```
3 1 8 4 5 0 8 2 9
```

Now, the recursive step should be to sort all the values to the left of the pivot, and all the values to the right. And we leave the pivot alone because partitioning ensured that it is in its final position.

There are no values to the right of the pivot so we should be making a recursive call for the range 0 to 7. But if you inspect what happens with your code you will find that it does not. Instead it makes a recursive call for the range 0 to 8. That in itself is a little benign, but once the ranges become small, at the stopping condition, it's different. Try asking your program to sort these values:

```
1 2
```

The code pivots on `1`. At the end of partitioning we have:

```
links = 0
rechts = 1
l = 0
r = 0
```

So we recursively call `quickSort` passing `l` and `rechts` as the ranges. But that's exactly the same call as we initially made. And that therefore leads to a stack overflow.

So the point is that we must make sure that when we partition on a pivot, we exclude that pivot from all future recursive calls to `quickSort`. If we don't do that we don't sub-divide the problem, and the recursion does not terminate.

Comment: Thank you.
What is the problem with not incrementing/decrementing?
The values are exchanged  and l is still smaller than r and the while loop should continue as it is supposed to.

Comment: Well, it's a different algorithm. One that does not work at all. You'll note that your original version differed.

Comment: Yes, but why does it not work?

My Example with the input
    3 1 8 4 9 0 8 2 5

Pivot: 9

after the first round, l will be 4(9) and r is 8(5):
They are exchanged. So the array is:

    3 1 8 4 5 0 8 2 9

Why do I have to inc/and dec?
If I dont, the next turn l will inc and r will be dec by the two inner while loops anyways

Comment: What are you using as your source text for this? There are countless different ways to implement partitioning. It's easy enough to see that your code fails to partition. Why did you change the code from your previous version that works to this version that does not? Does your source text tell you to do so?

Comment: I added some analysis that shows why you get a stack overflow

Comment: Thank you. That was a hell of an answer! :)